# Printing MirroredElemTypes in Scala 3

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3, dotty, generic-derivation

I am trying to modify [this](https://github.com/adamw/scala3-macro-pres/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/softwaremill/funscala/S180_TypeclassDerivation.scala) standard example to print values with the types.
And I am stuck with `p.MirroredElemTypes`. I haven't found any API to traverse and stringify types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check `MirroredElemTypes` you can just summon

```
import scala.deriving.Mirror

case class A(i: Int, s: String, b: Boolean)

val m = summon[Mirror.Of[A]]
summon[m.MirroredElemTypes =:= (Int, String, Boolean)] // compiles
```

But if you want to print `MirroredElemTypes` you can do the following.

For some reason `Typeable` doesn't work now but in its error message it prints the type

```
// scalaVersion := "3.0.2"
// libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "shapeless3-typeable" % "3.0.3"
import shapeless3.typeable.Typeable

summon[Typeable[m.MirroredElemTypes]].describe
// Typeable for sum type scala.*:[scala.Int, scala.*:[scala.Predef.String, scala.*:[scala.Boolean, scala.Tuple$package.EmptyTuple]]] with no Mirror
```

Alternatively you can write a simple macro

```
import scala.quoted.*

inline def describe[A]: String = ${describeImpl[A]}

def describeImpl[T: Type](using Quotes): Expr[String] = {
  import quotes.reflect.*
  Literal(StringConstant(TypeRepr.of[T].dealias.show)).asExprOf[String]
}

// in a different file
describe[m.MirroredElemTypes]
// scala.*:[scala.Int, scala.*:[scala.Predef.String, scala.*:[scala.Boolean, scala.Tuple$package.EmptyTuple]]]
```

---

In Scala 3.2.0 + Shapeless 3.2.0 `Typeable` works properly

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/1R6N3ZOJS46DJJqtQDU0lw