# scala 3 get field types of case class

Tags: scala, inline, scala-3, generic-derivation

I try get head type and write it to List

```
transparent inline def getClassesFieldType[A](using p: Mirror.ProductOf[A]): List[String] =
    inline p match {
      case m: Mirror.ProductOf[A] =>
        summonFieldTypes[m.MirroredElemTypes]
    }

  transparent inline def summonFieldTypes[T <: Tuple]: List[String] =
    inline erasedValue[T] match {
      case _: (head *: tail) =>
        
      case _ => Nil
    }
```

i try this

```
transparent inline def getClassesFieldType[A](using p: Mirror.ProductOf[A]): List[String] =
    inline p match {
      case m: Mirror.ProductOf[A] =>
        summonFieldTypes[m.MirroredElemTypes]
    }

  transparent inline def summonFieldTypes[T <: Tuple]: List[String] =
    inline erasedValue[T] match {
      case _: (head *: tail) =>
        summonInline[head].toString :: summonFieldTypes[tail]
      case _ => Nil
    }
```

also i try this

```
transparent inline def getClassesFieldType[A](using p: Mirror.ProductOf[A]): List[String] =
    inline p match {
      case m: Mirror.ProductOf[A] =>
        summonFieldTypes[m.MirroredElemTypes]
    }

  transparent inline def summonFieldTypes[T <: Tuple]: List[String] =
    inline erasedValue[T] match {
      case _: (head *: tail) =>
        constValue[head].toString :: summonFieldTypes[tail]
      case _ => Nil
    }
```

but this dont work because different excaption
like No given instance of type String was found getClassesFieldType[Tester]
or not a constant type: String; cannot take constValue getClassesFieldType[Tester]

Answer (score 1):

after 4 hours and after 5 minutes after post i did this

```
transparent inline def summonFieldTypes[T <: Tuple]: List[String] =
    inline erasedValue[T] match {
      case _: (head *: tail) =>
        inline erasedValue[head] match
          case _:String => "String" :: summonFieldTypes[tail]
          case _:Option[String] => "Option[String]" :: summonFieldTypes[tail]
          case _:Int => "Int" :: summonFieldTypes[tail]
      case _ => Nil
    }
```

Comment: This is not generic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use type class `Typeable` from [Shapeless-3](https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-3)

```scala
import scala.compiletime.erasedValue
import scala.deriving.Mirror
import shapeless3.typeable.Typeable

inline def getClassesFieldType[A](using p: Mirror.ProductOf[A]): List[String] =
  summonFieldTypes[p.MirroredElemTypes]

inline def summonFieldTypes[T <: Tuple]: List[String] =
  inline erasedValue[T] match
    case _: (head *: tail) => Typeable[head].describe :: summonFieldTypes[tail]
    case _ => Nil
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/FYv3PQYvTaKGe02xgoKTWg/1

[Printing MirroredElemTypes in Scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747525/printing-mirroredelemtypes-in-scala-3/)